# Write HKLM when installed as Administrator, but HKCU otherwise, in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, registry, inno-setup, administrator

I've created my Inno Setup installer and it is working great.  I just have one issue I'd like to solve.  Not all of my users have Administrator rights, so my app has been set up to allow non admins to install.  The problem is, I have set up a file association for my application and consequently need to set the correct registry keys for this.

As my users aren't all Administrators, I can't just use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (`HKLM`).  At the moment, I'm defaulting to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (`HKCU`).

Is there an elegant way to conditionally set `HKLM` if the user is an Administrator (selected the "install for all users" option) and `HKCU` if the users selects install to their own profile?

Comment: Looks like I was just blind....

Comment: HKA (equals HKLM in administrative install mode, HKCU otherwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this will do the trick:

`HKA` (equals `HKLM` in administrative install mode, `HKCU` otherwise)

Testing it now.